# How fast is the R sparklyr package as a front end for Spark?

Tags: python, r, scala, apache-spark, sparklyr

I've read online that Scala is faster than Python, e.g. [here](https://www.dezyre.com/article/scala-vs-python-for-apache-spark/213). I've also seen a comparison between different front ends that concluded that R was so slow that the tester gave up trying to measure its performance ([here](https://mindfulmachines.io/blog/2018/6/apache-spark-scala-vs-java-v-python-vs-r-vs-sql26); although this was specifically a test for user-defined functions and may not have used the `sparklyr` package).

I also know that `sparklyr` now has `arrow` integration, which has led to performance improvements for user defined functions as well as copying data to/from the cluster, as shown [here](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2019/01/25/r-spark-improvements/).

**My question: how fast is `sparklyr` compared to Python/Scala?** I'm mostly interested in standard 'out-of-the-box' functions, but would also be interested to know how it stacks up for user-defined functions now that `arrow` has been integrated. And are there particular circumstances in which it performs well or badly?

I ask because I've built an app in `sparklyr` that is slower than I would have hoped despite lots of tinkering with tuning parameters, and I'm wondering if this is partly because of limitations in the package.

Comment: Given that you already have an app in **R** I would rather write the same in **Scala** and benchmark both. That way you will a real measure of how fast / slow it is.

Comment: Here's one comparison: https://jozef.io/r201-spark-r-1/, though it's not quite the full comparison you're suggesting.

Comment: @r2evans thank you for that link. So as I understand it this means that the 'out of the box' sparklyr functions are just a direct interface to Spark, translating dplyr syntax into Spark SQL. So performance should be similar to directly using Spark SQL? If so then the question becomes how fast Spark SQL is vs Python and Scala...

Comment: I think so. I've not seen anything about "native R in Spark" without the data's round-trip to some R process. That is, I suspect that python in a spark pipeline can use python natively on each Spark node (complete speculation, I have no experience there), but have seen nothing about R on each node. (This would only mitigate network r/t times ...)

Answer (score -1):

in a local PC, most of the time, R is much faster than spark.